# Convert Timestamp with MM:SS.MS to MM:SS.MS without date R

Tags: r, timestamp, lubridate, milliseconds

I need to convert a video timestamp with minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to use in logicals for filtering. (ie: VideoTime < 00:02:30) I need to subset out only portions of my data for the statistics. I'm using R Studio 1.2.1335 on a Mac OSX HighSierra.

I've tried converting from a factor to a character into Posix.ct, strptime, strftime, hms (lubridate), as.duration(lubridate), and chron.

I hope the formatting below comes out correctly, as I've tried to use the Markdown instructions (but usually to write code in Markdown I use ctrl+option+i, which doesn't work here).

````
    options(digits.secs=2)
    test1=strftime(test1, format='%M:%OS2')
    test2=hms(EAllFilt$Video.Time)
    test3=test2 %>% as.duration(dminutes(2), dseconds(4))
    test4=strptime(EAllFilt$Video.Time, '%M:%SO2')
    test5=as.chron(times(EAllFilt$Video.Time, format="m:s"))```


    >EAllFilt$Video.Time=as.character(EAllFilt$Video.Time)
    > str(EAllFilt)
'data.frame':   7665 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Video.Time: chr  "00:00.0" "00:00.2" "00:00.4" "00:00.6" ...
 $ Valence   : num  379 378 358 218 612 686 698 688 684 689 ...
 $ Subject   : Factor w/ 5 levels "50132","50142",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Session   : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

    > head(EAllFilt$Video.Time)
[1] "00:00.0" "00:00.2" "00:00.4" "00:00.6" "00:00.8" "00:01.0"

    > tail(EAllFilt$Video.Time)
[1] "02:24.4" "02:24.6" "02:24.8" "02:25.0" "02:25.2" "02:25.4"

    > options(digits.secs=2)

    > test1=strftime(test1, format='%M:%OS2')
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
    > class(test1)
[1] "character"
    > tail(test1)
[1] "02:24.4" "02:24.6" "02:24.8" "02:25.0" "02:25.2" "02:25.4"

    > test2=hms(EAllFilt$Video.Time)
    > class(test2)
[1] "Period"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lubridate"
    > str(test2)
Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
  ..@ .Data : num [1:7665] 0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8 ...
  ..@ year  : num [1:7665] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ month : num [1:7665] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ day   : num [1:7665] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ hour  : num [1:7665] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ minute: num [1:7665] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    > head(test2)
[1] "0S"    "2S"    "4S"    "6S"    "8S"    "1M 0S"
    > tail(test2)
[1] "2H 24M 4S" "2H 24M 6S" "2H 24M 8S" "2H 25M 0S" "2H 25M 2S" "2H 25M 4S"

    > test3=test2 %>% as.duration(dminutes(2), dseconds(4))
Error in .local(x, ...) : unused arguments (dminutes(2), dseconds(4))
    > class(test3)
[1] "Duration"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lubridate"
    > str(test3)
Formal class 'Duration' [package "lubridate"] with 1 slot
  ..@ .Data: num [1:7665] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
    > tail(test3)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

    > test4=strptime(EAllFilt$Video.Time, '%M:%SO2')
    > class(test4)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 
    > str(test4)
 POSIXlt[1:7665], format: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
    > head(test4)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
    > tail(test4)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

    > test5=as.chron(times(EAllFilt$Video.Time, format="m:s"))
Error in convert.times(times., fmt) : format m:s may be incorrect


Test 2, using lubridate, seems to be closest to what I'l need but it thinks that I'm using HH:MM.SS and rather than MM:SS.ms (see "tail(test4)"
````

Comment: I'm not a `chron` user, string comparisons still work: `"47:31.744" < "47:56.744"` is true. It can fail if you have an hour-wraparound, where `"10:59:59.000"` is less than `"11:00:00.000"`, but the shortened `"59:59.000"` is not less than `"00:00.000"`. If you truly need just comparability, either convert them to `numeric` (using `strsplit`, `as.numeric`, and some multiplication) or make then `POSIXt` all on the same day, perhaps `strptime(paste0("2000-01-01 12:", EAllFilt$Video.Time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")`.

Comment: I checked my local time and it was correct, so I thought that using strptime was supposed to automatically add today's date, but it didn't. Since strptime formatted to Posixlt above (rather than ct), the logicals didn't work for filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I found:

`test6=period_to_seconds(hms(EAllFilt$Video.Time))
class(test6)
[1] "numeric"
head(test6)
[1]  0  2  4  6  8 60
tail(test6) #this one is best!
[1] 8644 8646 8648 8700 8702 8704`

It saves the millisecond data as seconds, but it is stuill usable for my purposes